# Would it be possible to have a humanoid without iron in circulation in its blood/body?

Tags: biology, xenobiology

Would it be possible to have a humanoid, a human looking species with a roughly equivalent brain to humans,  without iron in circulation in its blood or body?

I have found that reptiles could be a possible candidate as the do not have red blood cells but was unable to find out if they could look near human.

Comment: Reptiles have hemoglobin just like we do. Their blood is as red as ours. (And their blood does have erythrocytes; I don't know why you thought it doesn't. The difference between mammalian and reptilian erythrocytes is that in reptiles, red blood cells are regular cells with a nucleus and can live for a much longer time than mammalian red blood cells, which lack a nucleus.) (P.S. We don't have iron in our blood. We have hemoglobin, a substance of which the molecules contain iron atoms. Hemoglobin and iron are very different substances, with very different physical and chemical properties.)

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, but hemoglobin is more likely**

There are lots of oxygen-transporting metalloproteins, including hemocyanin, hemerythrin, chlorocruorin, vanabins (maybe), and coboglobin. Many of these are used in other groups of animals (squids, insects, sea squirts).

However, all vertebrates use hemoglobin as their blood protein with the exception of [Antarctic ice fishes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channichthyidae). This isn't the reason why hemoglobin is more likely, however. First, hemoglobin seems to be really easy to evolve, it has evolved independently (with minor differences in protein structure suggesting separate evolutionary events) in vertebrates, [annelid worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riftia_pachyptila), and a bunch of other groups. Secondly, it also transports oxygen more efficiently than almost any other protein. Hemocyanin, the next most common substitute, only outperforms hemoglobin in colder temperatures and high pressures (which is one of several reasons why squid, which use hemocyanin, do so well at the bottom of the ocean compared to fishes). Large brains do better with more oxygenation, so hemoglobin is more useful for a sapient species (though octopi do use hemocyanin).

The reptile example you are thinking of is *[Prasinohaema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prasinohaema)*, which has green blood due to high bile concentrations in their blood. This is a plausible alternative reason why your species might have non-red blood: it is due to an accessory pigment that plays a role in immune response or clotting and overshadows the red of hemoglobin.

Answer (score 3):

Iron, in the form of haemoglobin, isn't the only way to transport oxygen around. [Haemocyanins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemocyanin), using copper, are found in various flavours of marine invertebrate including quite intelligent cephalopods like octopus. This suggests that although it isn't quite as good at transporting oxygen as haemoglobin, it doesn't preclude some form of fairly capable brain. Wikipedia informs me there are other oxygen bearing things too, including a synthetic cobalt-based one in the form of [coboglobin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coboglobin).

It is entirely possible that there exist some or many other kinds of metalloprotein that can do just as good a job as haemoglobin. I'm sure you could handwave one into your setting without issue, so long as you didn't go into too much detail.

I would not necessarily expect a non-iron-bearing-oxygen-transport-protein-using vertebrate to evolve from eg. an octopus, and then colonise the land and end up looking like a primate, though. One could perhaps be engineered, though the fact that something so alien looked so familiar would be a big red flag that it was artificial to anyone who thought about it for very long.